# z-index error in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have two divs having the same dimensions. one div is placed over the other. whenever i needed the reverse, i assigned z-index for the other div. it's working fine in chrome. but in internet explorer, the `z-index: -1` element is completly hidden. why is this happening? i tested this with the latest Internet Explorer 10. has this happened before for any of u guys?

Comment: Hm, what exactly do you expect from an element with a negative z-index? *negative* index means, it's lying behind the parent element (if no specific value for z-index being declared on it) - thus it's of course completely hidden.

Comment: Older IE versions did have issues with `z-index`. Newer IE versions should be fine, but if you're in compatibility mode or quirks mode, you may still get the old-style behaviour. Can you confirm what mode your browser is in? (use F12 to bring up the dev tools to find out)

Comment: It's said at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "`... A positive value positions the element above text that has no defined z-index, and a negative value positions it below. ...`"

Answer (score 0):

Keep z-indexes as positive numbers. I'd assign your elements a default z-index, then have a display class that you added to one or the other of them (using jquery etc.) that make the z-index a higher number.

```
.item { z-index: 10; }
.item.display { z-index: 20; }
```